# Cursor misaligned in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview, cursor-position

I have a textview. When it is clicked, the blue cursor appears in the textView. However, this blue cursor is too high up. It is not centered. Thus, the upper part of the blue cursor is cut off. This is what it looks like:

[image]

As soon as any text is typed into the textView the blue cursor then moves lower. Thus, as soon as any text is typed, the blue cursor is somewhat centered in the screen. As you can see here, the positioning of the blue cursor here is different from the positioning of the blue cursor before. This is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I make it such that the positioning of the blue cursor is the same in both cases?

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var userMessageTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.userMessageTextView.delegate = self

        //Used to make the border of the TextView look the same as the border of a TextField
        userMessageTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        userMessageTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        userMessageTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        //Used to Make the Cursor appear somewhat centered in the TextView; Without this, the bottom of the cursor is lined up with the bottom edge of the TextView, so the cursor is not centered within the textView
        userMessageTextView.contentOffset.y = 4.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check textContainetInset of UITextView.

[textContainerInset from Apple doc's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618619-textcontainerinset)

Comment: In ViewDidLoad, TextViewDidBeginEditing, and TextViewDidChange, the value of myTextView.textContainerInset is UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 0.0).

Comment: Do you have any constraints in XIB or Storyboard files? Did you change the TextView font default value?

Comment: I have constraints in Main.storyboard, however these constraints are only for labels within a cell inside of a tableView. I have no constraints for the TextView. I changed the TextView font default value. Its initial value (after you drag it in from the Object Library) is System 14.0. Using the Utilities Inspector in Main.storyboard, I changed this value to System 17.0.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are giving a fixed height to the TextView and text font is not set to match the height.

In any case, UITextField is much better suited to your use case. I would advise you to use it instead.

Comment: I cannot use a UITextField because a UITextField does not allow there to be more than one line. Only a UITextView can have more than one line.

Comment: @Everett: Are you changing font in any of UITextView Delegate methods?

Comment: I am not changing the font anywhere. The font is set (in Main.storyboard) to be System 17.0. I do not change it anywhere. Also, the height of the TextView is not changed anywhere. The height is set (in Main.storyboard) to be 30.

Comment: @Everett: If the height is set 30, how do you suppose it to be multiline?

Comment: I expect to add the multiline functionality later. Later, I will change the height programmatically, increasing the height using the ViewController if there is more than one line of text. Right now, I am just trying to make the cursor appear centered in the textView whenever the user presses it. The user will use the keyboard to type into the textView.

Comment: @Everett: Looks like you dont want Textview to be scrolling. For your use-case, dont give nay height to UITextview and disable its scrolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171953/discussion-between-everett-and-puneet-sharma).